# How to find an analytic $f:G\to\mathbb C$, where $G=\{z:Re(z)>0\}$, such that $f(G)=D=\{z:|z|<1\}$ using a Mobius Transformation?

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-explanation, mobius-transformation

The following example is taken from Conway's book, *Functions of One Complex Variable I*.

> Find an analytic function $f:G\to\mathbb C$, where $G=\{z:Re(z)>0\}$, such that $f(G)=D=\{z:|z|<1\}$.

Conway's explanation towards a solution is as follows:

[image]
[image]

However, I have the following questions regarding the explanation above:

- Why $\{z:\Im(z,-i,0,i)>0\}=\{z:\Im(iz)>0\} ?$
- How does $T:=R^{-1}\circ S$ map the imaginary axis onto the circle $\Gamma\subset\mathbb C_\infty ?$
- How did he arrive at the expression $g(z)=\dfrac{e^z -1}{e^z+1}$ from the expression for $Tz$ ?

I understood his calculations other than these three conclusions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand Conway's notation,  but, this should be pretty straightforward using Cayley's transform and a rotation.

That is,  $$f(z)=\frac{z-i}{z+i}$$ maps the upper half plane onto the unit circle.

So you just need to compose with a rotation by $\pi/2$. That's multiplication by $i$.

The result is $$\frac {z-1}{z+1}$$.

Comment: Thanks, but I am not used to Cayley's Transform (at least not yet). Could you show this in line with Conway's arguments?

Comment: Well,  I'm not exactly sure what he means by an "orientation".  I don't have the book.  Why he's concerned with that horizontal strip I don't know.   But it results in $e^z$.

Comment: His definition of an _orientation_ is as follows:\\
"If $\Gamma$ is a circle then an orientation for $\Gamma$ is an ordered triple 
of points $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ such that each $z_j$ is in $\Gamma$."

Comment: He also proved the **Orientation Principle** which states

"Let $\Gamma_1$ and $\Gamma_2$ be two circles in $\mathbb C_{\infty}$ and let $T$ be a Mobius transformation such that $T(\Gamma_1) =\Gamma_2$. Let $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ be an orientation for $\Gamma_1$. Then $T$ takes the right side and the left side of $\Gamma_1$ onto the right and left side of $\Gamma_2$ with respect to the orientation $(Tz_1, Tz_2 , Tz_3)$."

Comment: Hmm, well,  he's done this from scratch I guess.   But Cayley's transform makes this easy.   To learn it, just check the images of $-1,0,1$.  You'll find they're on the unit circle.   Then use a test point, like $i$, to see that the upper half plane indeed maps onto the unit disk.  That's the way I would do it.

Comment: Okay, understood your argument now.